# Node.js callback error and result clarification

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have a question regarding Node.js callbacks. Specifically, do ALL node.js callbacks have `(err, res)` as parameters? I get confused because sometimes I see functions that have `(req, res)` as parameters and I am unsure of which to use... Any documentation on this would be very helpful...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters that are accepted by callback function depend completely on callback function 'design'.
From your post I would make assumption that you are dealing with http related methods, thats why you see `(err, req, res)`. If you look at `fs.readFile('text.txt', function (err, data) { ... })`, parameters are different (you can call them whatever you want by the way).

I'll try to explain it on example of custom build callback function:

```
function useAsCallback(string){
  console.log("callback function says: " + string)
}

function main(someString, callback){
  callback(someString)
}

main('What a great callback', useAsCallback)
```